# Building react native project on xcode takes for ever (very slow) on the process Running 1 of 1 custom shell script

Tags: node.js, react-native, watchman

It seems a strange behavior. I have zsh and for development I use nvm 
But I also seem to have node installed by brew.

[image: React native defaul config]

The packager runs but the xcode appears to wait till the packager is ready but It is already!

So I take more than 20 minutes !!
When it used to be very fast.

Not sure if it is watchman, node version, bash. Or something else. But it is driving my crazy,

Hope you could help me find a solution.

Versions:
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
node --version
v6.11.2

What version of node is recommended to work with React Native?

Comment: Did you find any solutions for this? My builds take forever.

Comment: No, I opened an [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15469#issuecomment-366722253)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clearing your caches within Xcode?

[How to Empty Caches and Clean All Targets Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714372/how-to-empty-caches-and-clean-all-targets-xcode-4)

Other than that have you ensured your PATH is setup properly with the version of react-native you're trying to execute?

Comment: How can I ensure my PATH is setup properly?